# statistics on port 22 blocking

Tags: firewall, port, blocking

What are the statistics on port 22 blocking by firewalls in small and medium sized enterprises?  We have a product that a customer installs on a PC, which communicates via ssh to our cloud server. It would be good to know how common port 22 blocking is.

Comment: Survey-type questions like these aren't a good fit for SF, as they don't have an objective answer. My feeling on the issue is: if a company wants to purchase your product, you should disclose that it needs connectivity to your IP address on port 22, and that they will need to permit that traffic.

Comment: Statistics are objective. I used the word statistics near the start of the q for that reason. Hopefully someone here has an answer, tho maybe I should be asking Google instead.

Answer (score 1):

TCP/22 blocking is common enough you should have documentation in your product, or it's support site, at release describing why this is needed. When requirements assessment is done at a customer, this sort of information up front can turn aside some nasty complaints after deployment and they find it doesn't work.

Aggressive egress filtering is much more common in some industries than others, so there will be variation depending on who you're selling to. However, ultra-paranoids can crop up anywhere so be ready for it.